# getting exception while importing .jar file in jboss

Tags: wicket, jboss6.x

I am using wicket 1.4 and jboss 6.2 versoin. while importing .jar file i am getting following exception :full stack trace is here :
Please provide solution thanx in advance.

```
03:25:23,279 WARN  [org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form] (http-/10.157.250.196:25005-112) Upload failed: null: org.apache.wicket.util.upload.FileUploadException
at org.apache.wicket.util.upload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:404) [wicket-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at org.apache.wicket.util.upload.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:129) [wicket-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.servlet.MultipartServletWebRequest.<init>(MultipartServletWebRequest.java:155) [wicket-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.servlet.MultipartServletWebRequest.<init>(MultipartServletWebRequest.java:83) [wicket-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.servlet.ServletWebRequest.newMultipartWebRequest(ServletWebRequest.java:489) [wicket-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.handleMultiPart(Form.java:1708) [wicket-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:886) [wicket-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.onEvent(AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.java:135) [wicket-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxEventBehavior.respond(AjaxEventBehavior.java:177) [wicket-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.onRequest(AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java:300) [wicket-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.listener.BehaviorRequestTarget.processEvents(BehaviorRequestTarget.java:119) [wicket-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:92) [wicket-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1250) [wicket-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1329) [wicket-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1436) [wicket-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545) [wicket-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:484) [wicket-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:317) [wicket-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.12.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.12.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.12.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.12.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.5.12.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.12.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.5.12.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.12.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.5.5.Final-redhat-3.jar:7.5.5.Final-redhat-3]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150) [jbossweb-7.5.12.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.12.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.5.12.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.12.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.5.12.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.12.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:559) [jbossweb-7.5.12.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.12.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.5.12.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.12.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Http11NioProcessor.java:355) [jbossweb-7.5.12.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.12.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:911) [jbossweb-7.5.12.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.12.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$ChannelProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:936) [jbossweb-7.5.12.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.12.Final-redhat-1]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_85]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_85]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$DefaultThreadFactory$1$1.run(NioEndpoint.java:1249) [jbossweb-7.5.12.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.12.Final-redhat-1]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_85]
```

Caused by: ClientAbortException:  java.io.EOFException: JBWEB002011: Socket read failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:371) [jbossweb-7.5.12.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.12.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:422) [jbossweb-7.5.12.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.12.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:393) [jbossweb-7.5.12.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.12.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:193) [jbossweb-7.5.12.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.12.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.upload.MultipartFormInputStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartFormInputStream.java:1151) [wicket-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.upload.MultipartFormInputStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartFormInputStream.java:1034) [wicket-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.io.Streams.copy(Streams.java:154) [wicket-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.io.Streams.copy(Streams.java:126) [wicket-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.upload.MultipartFormInputStream.readBodyData(MultipartFormInputStream.java:658) [wicket-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.upload.MultipartFormInputStream.discardBodyData(MultipartFormInputStream.java:687) [wicket-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.upload.MultipartFormInputStream.skipPreamble(MultipartFormInputStream.java:707) [wicket-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.upload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.findNextItem(FileUploadBase.java:1071) [wicket-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.upload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.(FileUploadBase.java:1045) [wicket-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.upload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:344) [wicket-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at org.apache.wicket.util.upload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:364) [wicket-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    ... 34 more

Answer (score 1):

- This is indicating that the other end (the ajp proxy) closed the connection for some reason (possibly a timeout if the larger files take significantly longer to transfer).
- The server side error is the result of a timeout hit while trying to read the request body from the client. So keepalive connection times out at the proxy layer and is closed, but the client tries to reuse it. After the expected RST, the client tries a new connection, but the client doesn't properly send the POST body in this case on the new connection. Thus JBoss eventually times out waiting for the post body that never comes, resulting in the exception.
- The above errors indicates that there has been a long running socket read operation , and for some reason  the front end apache hits a timeout .
- You will need to explore/analyse the httpd logs around the same time to investigate this further.
- Capture tcp dumps and check for a missing request body from the client.
- Disable keepalive on httpd to avoid the client's broken keepalive handling:

  Keepalive Off

Answer (score 0):

`ClientAbortException: java.io.EOFException` means that the browser has closed the connection to the server before sending the complete data. Maybe the user has closed the browser tab/window.